# Determining types of geometry in a single table?

Tags: postgis, geometry, filter, where-clause

I need to determine whether any tables within my database have more than one geometry type. For example, I want to know if there are Points AND multipoints within the same table.

Currently, I have been using the command "ST_ASEWKT" to convert the "geom" column into EWKT and scrolling through the results, trying to find more than one geometry type.
But I have table with over 50,000 records.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a given table, you can list the distinct types using [`geometryType()`](https://postgis.net/docs/GeometryType.html)

```
SELECT DISTINCT geometryType(geom)
FROM mytable;
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of this command, but it has achieved what I was having problems with!